# result of searching in arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

I am using fuse.js to search in arrays of objects like http://fusejs.io/#searching-in-arrays-of-objects

It returns the whole item with the tag matched.
How do I know which of the tags is matched?

Answer (score 0):

When you set your options, set **verbose** to **true**.  This will log matching scores, with the matched key, to the console.

```
const options = {
  verbose: true,
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "title",
    "author.firstName"
  ]
};
const fuse = new Fuse(list, options);
```